# How to include controller.js files in partials in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The one problem I have with angular.js apps from what I can tell is every single ".js" file be it a service, controller, factory, etc. all needs to be referenced or included in the "index.html" file or something like it causing the end user to have to download all JS at one time, which can be really big if you've got a lot of "modules".

Is there a way in angular to make it such that instead of referencing those ".js" files all in the index.html, to make it so that each ".html" partial contains script tages referencing say: MyDirectiveAndController.js that is never included in "index.html", but is included in MyDirectiveAndController.html (assuming that this is a specific directive that is not always available to the user unless a user clicks on a specific link).

I want to save bandwidth from having a user load in more than they actually need at the start, and linking to every single directive and controller that could possibly be used in the application, or combining everything into a single fat minified js file does not seem to solve that issue.

I am open to alternatives to solve this problem.

Comment: There are several articles about lazy loading with Require.js.  Worth a look...

Comment: Is there a way around it without require.js? I heard requirejs adds unnecessary overhead. Not sure if this is accurate.